# Firefox says could not download the search plugin from

Tags: javascript, xml, firefox, firefox-addon, opensearch

**Backstory:**
I'm trying to dynamically generate an [OpenSearch](http://www.opensearch.org/Specifications/OpenSearch/Extensions/Suggestions/1.1) search plugin for Firefox based on user entered values as part of a larger add-on. I'm not including the forms and cruft surrounding it, because I've narrowed it down to a simple failing test case trying to import any XML.

**Code:** 
*Simplified JS*

```
var browserSearchService = Components
        .classes["@mozilla.org/browser/search-service;1"]
        .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIBrowserSearchService);

var EngineProperties = {
                xml :   'http://localhost/search.xml',
                dataType: 3,
                iconURL : 'http://localhost/logo.png',
                confirm : false,
                callback : function addEngineCallback(){
                    console.log('Jason is the greatest');           
                }
            }

browserSearchService.addEngine( EngineProperties.xml,
                                            EngineProperties.dataType,
                                            EngineProperties.iconURL,
                                            EngineProperties.confirm,
                                            EngineProperties.callback);
```

*Actual XML*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OpenSearchDescription xmlns="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/"
                       xmlns:moz="http://www.mozilla.org/2006/browser/search/">
  <ShortName>Jason</ShortName>
  <Description>Powered By Jason</Description>
  <InputEncoding>UTF-8</InputEncoding>
  <Image width="16" height="16" type="image/x-icon">http://localhost/logo.png</Image>

  <URL method="get" type="text/html" template="http://search.mywebsearch.com/mywebsearch/GGmain.jhtml?ptb=100000487&amp;ind=1406730191685&amp;n=14787A74345&amp;st=bar&amp;searchfor={searchTerms}" />
  <URL method="get" type="application/x-moz-keywordsearch" 
    template="http://search.mywebsearch.com/mywebsearch/GGmain.jhtml?&amp;ptb=100000487&amp;ind=1406730191685&amp;n=14787A74345&amp;st=bar&amp;searchfor={searchTerms}" />
  <Url method="get" type="application/x-suggestions+json" 
    template="http://ssmsp.ask.com/query?q={searchTerms}&amp;li=ff&amp;sstype=prefix"/>

  <moz:SearchForm>http://search.mywebsearch.com/mywebsearch/GGmain.jhtml</moz:SearchForm>
</OpenSearchDescription>
```

*(From the [Mycroft Project](http://mycroftproject.com/submitos.html))*

From what I've seen the error should indicate an invalid XML file, but for the life of me I can't find anything wrong with this. I've loaded it in Firefox fixed all the typos and syntactical errors I found (used to have `&` instead of `&amp;`, and the browser displays and parses it fine, but yet it won't load as an open search search engine.

Does FF not support localhost, maybe? I'm drawing a blank here.

Thanks in advance for any insight!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problems:**
As indicated by [Noitidart](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1828637/noitidart), [`dataType` should be 1 even though it's opensearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25083992/firefox-says-could-not-download-the-search-plugin-from/25169469#25128617).

Second, cannot pass the `iconURL` in `addEngine`. Not sure if that's true for all icons, but definitely passing it a png or a `data URI` both failed.

Third, `callback` needs to be an object of the form:

```
callback={
    onError   : function(err){/**/},
    onSuccess : function(err){/**/}
}
```

Fourth the filetype should be `.osdx`, not `.xml`

`URL` to `url` to `Url` does not matter, never changed and extension working.

Lastly, when testing, ensure that you have `browser.search.log` set to `true` in `about:config`.

You can see more info at the bug report [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1048127).

Hope this helps the next guy stuck in `Components.classes["@mozilla.org/browser/search-service;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIBrowserSearchService).addEngine()`-land.

Update: Setting `confirm` to `true` results in:

```
[Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)
[nsIURI.host]"  nsresult: "0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)"  
location: "JS frame :: resource://gre/components/nsSearchService.js :: 
SRCH_SVC_confirmAddEngine :: line 1370"  
data: no]
```

So, don't do that.

It's nice how that API is so easily accessible. :|

Comment: Thanks man this is an awesome post. Is this on MDN somewhere? Especially about the callback. In which cases should we use dataType of 3 for opensearch?

Comment: To my knowledge, no. I got the info on the callback from Gavin on the ticket I had open on Bugzilla, and I got the data type by messing around, and then you confirmed. Also, sorry I spelled your u/n wrong in the answer... I no speel so gode.

Comment: dood ur talking to me :P i spell worse than you :P ask @nmaier :P and i never apologize :P

Answer (score 3):

It's a security thing. I was hit by this before. What I was doing was loading a xml file for overriding and xbl from a local path (or resource path or something I can't remember) and I would get xml error like it was syntax error but there was nothing. I couldn't figure it out.

Finally I created a `chrome.manifest` file and gave the path to the xml file like `chrome://myaddon/content/myxml.xml` and it worked. Super frustrating, the error should explain more, it wasted my time so much i was trying to fix the xml syntax...

So create that manifest than change your code here:

```
var EngineProperties = {
                xml :   'chrome://myaddon/content/search.xml',
                dataType: 3,
                iconURL : 'chrome://myaddon/content/logo.png',
                confirm : false,
                callback : function addEngineCallback(){
                    console.log('Jason is the greatest');           
                }
            }
```

notice how i removed the local path with the chrome path.

so ya apparently xml files have to be loaded from chrome paths in order to work right.

Now if you would like to host this thing on the net and install it like that, then you have to use the non-privelaged way of installing (which means excecute this javascript from an html page). Which is this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Adding_search_engines_from_web_pages

```
window.external.AddSearchProvider('http://localhost/search.xml');
```

but if you want to install it like you are doing in your topic post, which is xpcom install, you have to use chrome path

Comment: can I use a data URI with `window.external.AddSearchProvider`?

Comment: Also, even after changing to chrome protocol, still nothing. Gotta be an xml issue, but can't figure out what it is.

Comment: I think data uri should work fine. Can you send me your actual xml files. Post it up on github and Ill get this to work. Did the xml file work with `window.external.AddSearchProvider`?

Comment: That is my actual XML. it didn't work as a data:URI or with a chrome:// uri, but it worked when I created a host entry to a bogus domain and delivered it with the header 'Content-Type : application/opensearchdescription+xml'. Still doesn't help because I can't do that from within an add-on on a user's machine.

Comment: I don't think the security thing applies in this case. I'm not sure though.

Answer (score 2):

Ok I looked deeply into this and found out it was a very slight thing.

1. `dataType` in `EngineProperties` should be `1` which is `Ci.nsISearchEngine.DATA_XML` you were using `3` which is for `Ci.nsISearchEngine.TYPE_OPENSEARCH`. Yeah I know yours is an opensearch xml file but its xml so use use 1.
2. In the XML change `<URL` to `<Url` notice the lower case r and l. weird.

anyways you can install this addon here it installs your search engine:
https://github.com/yajd/PortableTester/tree/a9ed2432cf4fab4362b71d2c805d97caac2cd237

Use https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/github-extension-installer/ addon to install straight from repo.

LASTLY for I don't know what reason, but callback never calls after addEngine, it's so weird I have no idea how to get that to work :(

Also I'm not sure if the security error if not chrome path is true, not sure but it might be in other cases, but maybe not here. You should be able to do localhost or or local file paths like `file:///C:/blah.xml`