# How find UUID of a Mozilla OpenSearch addon?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, mozilla, uuid

I have developed a simple Mozilla add-on which consists of a single open search descriptor XML file.

Now I want to update my add-on with a new project generated by JetPack (still a search engine, but with many other features).

No problem to generate my XPI package, but when I try to publish the new XPI, I got the following error message:

```
"UUID doest not match the module"
```

How can I find the UUID of my "opensearch" add-on?

Comment: That's interesting can you post your code, I don't think i ran into this before. See this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25083992/firefox-says-could-not-download-the-search-plugin-from

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with OpenSearch addpms. But since they have no provision for a developer-supplied UUID, my guess is that one is automatically applied when they get published. If my guess is correct then you should be able to find on AMO. Click **Edit listing** and scroll down to **Technical Details**, it is the last entry.

Comment: Yes I can see the UUID field ... but it's empty!

Comment: Then I'm afraid you 're out of luck.

Comment: Look like they (Mozilla) consider OpenSearch module is not a real add-on.

Comment: Just to be sure, you get this message when you try to upload the xpi as a new version of the OpenSearch XML, right?

Comment: Not a new XML, since OpenSearch doest not work under Ubuntu, I decided to move to a JetPack bootstrapped project (with Javascript, package.json etc...), hence I need the UUID value.